# Array of own object

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I need to create a two-dimensional array of Person. How can I do that?

This is the object I created:

```
function Person() {
   var name;
   var children = new Array();
};
```

I would like to create a two-dimensional array of `Person`. For example:

```
["Ann", (child1, child2)] ["Peter", ()] ["John", (child1)]

["Steve", (child1)] ["Linda", (child1, child2, child3)] ["Vivian", ()]
```

Comment: By "matrix" you mean an array? Could you show an example of a result you want?

Comment: You need to create `name` and `children` as properties of `this`: `this.name = null; this.children = [];` What you've got there is variables local to the function `Person`. After the function exits, they'll be out of scope and they'll never be seen again. `[]` is shorthand for creating an empty array, same as `new Array()`.

Comment: @Juhana Thanks, I edit the main message

Comment: What happens when someone becomes a grandparent?

Comment: Do you want that structure as input to something that creates `Person` objects (parsing) or as something that's derived from an existing `Person`/collection of `Person`s (serialization)?  Both are possible, but the choice might dictate the design.

Comment: @ScottSauyet for serialization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you could use such a constructor and serialize it as expected:

```
var Person = function(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.children = [];
}

Person.prototype.addChild = function(child) {
  this.children.push(child);
}

Person.serialize = function(person) {
  return [person.name].concat([person.children.map(Person.serialize)]);
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
var fred = new Person('Fred');
fred.addChild(new Person('Pebbles'));
fred.addChild(new Person('Dino'));
Person.serialize(fred); //=> ["Fred", [["Pebbles", []], ["Dino", []]]]
```

Or like this:

```
var barney = new Person('Barney');
var bambam = new Person('Bam-bam');
barney.addChild(bambam);

var people = [fred, barney];
people.map(Person.serialize);
//=> [["Fred", [["Pebbles", []], ["Dino", []]]], ["Barney", [["Bam-bam",[]]]]]
```

Obviously there are many variations on this.

Comment: You're welcome.  Note that it might be good or bad news that this handles grandchildren and further descendants recursively.  They will just nest inside.  If you don't want that, you will actually have to write some more complex code.

Answer (score 0):

First, your constructor won't work. Your `var` things are local variables that will be gone when the function exits. This will do what I *think* you intend:

```
function Person() {
    this.name = null;
    //  This creates a new empty array same as new Array()
    this.children = [];
}
```

Second, an array of arrays is easy. Any reference in JavaScript can be a reference to anything. Here's an array of three arrays:

```
var arrayOfArrays = [ [], [], [] ];
```

Or you could do it this way:

```
var arrayOfArrays = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 20; ++i )
{
    arrayOfArrays[i] = [];
}
```

You can fill those arrays with anything you want, including `new Person()`.